# How to calculate local outlier detection (LOF)

Tags: data-mining, outliers

I want to have the correct calculation formula for the local outlier factor (LOF) according to the publication of Breunig & Sander.

I have found this formula:

> LOF = (Average of the lrd of the objects located in the MinPts area) divided through lrd of the suspected outlier, that is the centroid of the MinPts.

I am in doubt, if this is correct. Somebody said that the LOF is calculated as follows:

> LOF = (Average of the lrd of the objects located in the MinPts area including the lrd of the centroid i.e. the suspected ) divided through the lrd of the suspected outlier, that is the centroid of the MinPts.

What is the correct answer?

Comment: I have used the way shown in my answer from Dec 15: "For calculating LOF of an object You must take the average of the lrd of all objects contained in MinPts (without the suspected outlier object, the centroid) divided through the lrd of the object (suspected to be an outlier) / centroid. "

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, read the original source!

Because you want to use the definition of LOF by Breunig & Sander themselves, not by "somebody". And if I'd now say, e.g., "LOF is e^(I*pi)", would you next post the question "somebody on stack exchange said this, and someone else said something else"?

Go, and read the original source, if you need to verify a definition.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for Your answer. I have read the original publication of Breunig et al. But I must confess that I did not understand the correct formula to be used. Meanwhile I have got the answer. For claculating LOF of an object You must take the average of the lrd of all objects contained in MinPts (without the suspected outlier object, the centroid) divided through the lrd of lrd of the object (suspected to be an outlier) / centroid. The original publication has - by the way - some confounding definition of MinPts resp. k.